# Firebase Clooud Messaging Duplicate Push Notifivation

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `Firebase` for `push notification` in my ionic app. But unfortunately I am getting the same notification twice. I have searched through the net a lot and tried to apply all possible solutions found there but could not get it to work. My codes are as the following -

**Web end (PHP)**

```
$message_for_push = array(
    "data" => array(
        "title" => "New Notification",
        "body"  => "the message",
        "icon"  => "firebase-logo.png",
        'sound' => 'mySound',

        "type" => $message['type'],
        "section_id" => $message['section_id'],
        "isPush" => 1,
        "subdomain" => $subdomain, //dynamiic
        "id" => $message['id'],
        "other_key" => true
    ),
    /*"notification" => array(
        "title" => "New Notification",
        "body"  => $message['title'],
        "icon"  => "firebase-logo.png",
        'sound' => 'mySound',
        "type" => $message['type'],
        "section_id" => $message['section_id'],
        "isPush" => 1,
        "subdomain" => $subdomain, //dynamiic
        "id" => $message['id'],
    ),*/
    "registration_ids" =>  $registrationIds //array of device ids
);
$message_for_push = json_encode($message_for_push);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message_for_push,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: key=THE_KEY_GIVEN_HERE",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

**On the App End**

I have saved the `device id` on my web end at the time of first login. The token is saved only once. It does not change until or unless the app is re-installed.

```
this.firebase.getToken().then(token => {
    this.devicInfo.uuid = token;

    console.log( 'device_id>>>>>', token ); ///saved on web end
}).catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));
```

When the notification is received (Do not think any problem here)-

```
this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe((pushed_data) => {
    let alert = this.alert.create({
        title: 'Notification Received!',
        message: pushed_data,
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
});
```

The list of plugins used -

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
cordova-plugin-console
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-file
cordova-plugin-file-opener2
cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova-plugin-statusbar
cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player
cordova-sqlite-storage
ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if in your array of $registrationIds is there any duplicate ids ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I did check that and also have used `array_unique` to ensure it.

Comment: Your php script executes 2 times ?

Comment: The function is run through CRON. The CRON is set up using Laravels function. I did not find it running twice.Although if I use postman to call the function, I get single notification.